# can .on('click') be used to add to a number value?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, constants

I want my .on('click') function to add one to my number value every time the Html button is clicked. I can't find anywhere that has helped me and I have spent a long time looking and nothing helps. I have tried the basic numbers and math variables. but since I'm brand new to javascript I don't know where I'm going wrong

```js
import 'bootstrap@4.6.0'
import $ from 'jquery'
const number = {
  number:0  
};
$('button')
  .html('Click me') // Try edit it...
  .on('click')
```

```css
body {
  height: 100vh;
}
```

```html
<div class="d-flex h-100">
  <button class="btn btn-warning m-auto">
    Hi! Click me
  </button>
</div>
```

Comment: Please add the code you've attempted to your question as a [mcve].

Comment: ok i just did i forgot to add it so sorry

Comment: [`.on`](https://api.jquery.com/on/) requires an event handler which you haven't added. You can't just add `click` and then hope that something magical will happen.

Comment: Hi, if you're brand to JS, you should start by learning the basics rather than using jQuery or a framework.

Answer (score 0):

```html
<div class="d-flex h-100">
        <button class="btn btn-warning m-auto">
          Hi! Click me
        </button>
        <p id="result"></p>
      </div>
```

**Here is Plain Javascript**

```js
const addNum = document.querySelector('.btn');
let num = 0;
addNum.addEventListener('click', () =>{
    let result = document.querySelector('#result');
    result.innerHTML =num++;
});
```